# Evaluate an expression through a list of rule

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, rule

I have this iterative expression

```
A = (1/(2*1))*Sum[ (u[i, j, 3])^2 + (u[i, j, 4])^2, {i, 1, ndof1}, {j, 
1, ndof2}]
```

That I would like to evaluate using a list of rule.

```
rule3 = Table[If[Mod[i + j, 2] == 0,
     u[i, j, 3] -> 0,
    u[i, j, 3] -> 0]
    , {i, 1, 6}, {j, 1, 6}];
rule4 =  Table[If[Mod[i + j, 2] == 0,
     u[i, j, 4] -> 0,
     u[i, j, 4] -> 0]
     , {i, 1, 6}, {j, 1, 6}];
```

I put zeros to check if it works (A = 0). Next, I set

```
  A = A /. Flatten[rule3];
  A = A /. Flatten[rule4];
  A
```

I get

```
   0.0
```

Is there a way to do it in a better way? I mean for instance combining all the rules into a single one. By this way, I have 4 sets of rule_XX that is too heavy to carry along my code. I have to set rules to `u[i, j, 1], u[i, j, 2], u[i, j, 3], u[i, j, 4]`. Here, I show the two last ones.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure to understand your rules. For example, there will be some $i+j$, even, for $i\leq 6$ and $j\leq 6$ that cause that for $i=1\ldots 6$ and $j\ldots 6$ `u[i,j,3]=0` and `u[i,j,4]=0`, am I missing something ? If so, why not to start the sum at  $i=7$ and $j=7$ ?

Comment: If you're just looking to put rules in a single list, you can do `allRules = Flatten @ { rule3, rule4, ... }`.  You might even be able to generate all the rules in one `Table` -- e.g.,  `someRules=Flatten@Table[If[Mod[i + j, 2] == 0,
     u[i, j, k] -> 0,
    u[i, j, k] -> 0]
    , {i, 1, 6}, {j, 1, 6}, {k, 3, 4}]`

Comment: HI Jose, This is just a portion of my code that I made simpler in order to set my issue. Actually, the entire code is rather complex.

Comment: Many thanks jjc385. It works perfectly. And your new inputs on how I should create the rules worth.